# QProgressDialog no longer appearing after canceled

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt

I'm working with a PyQt GUI using a `QThread` to compute `result`. I also have a `QProgresDialog` on the main app to show the progress. I can rerun the computation multiple times and the dialog works. But, if I cancel the dialog once, it never shows up again, it is like it deletes itself so it can't be reused. How should I use `QProgressDialog` in order to use it multiple times even that I cancel the task?

Here is the minimal example:

```py
from time import sleep

from qtpy.QtCore import QThread, Signal  # type: ignore
from qtpy.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QCheckBox,
    QHBoxLayout,
    QProgressDialog,
    QWidget,
)


class WorkerThread(QThread):
    progress_changed = Signal(int)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.result = None

    def run(self):
        self.abort = False
        for i in range(100):
            print(f"\t{i}", end="\r")
            sleep(0.03)
            self.progress_changed.emit(i)
            if self.abort:
                return
        self.result = "We have a result"

    def quit(self):
        self.abort = True


class MyApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setFixedSize(300, 300)

        self.checkBox = QCheckBox("Compute something")
        self.worker = WorkerThread()
        self.progress_bar = QProgressDialog(
            "Computing background", "Cancel", 0, 100, self
        )

        self.checkBox.stateChanged.connect(self.CheckBox_changed)
        self.progress_bar.hide()
        self.progress_bar.setModal(True)
        self.progress_bar.canceled.connect(self.worker.quit)
        self.progress_bar.setMinimumDuration(1000)

        self.worker.progress_changed.connect(self.progress_bar.setValue)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.worker_finished)

        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        layout.addWidget(self.checkBox)

    def CheckBox_changed(self, checked):
        if checked:
            self.progress_bar.reset()
            self.worker.start()
        else:
            self.worker.result = None

    def worker_finished(self):
        self.progress_bar.reset()
        if self.worker.result is None:
            self.checkBox.setChecked(False)


app = QApplication([])
window = MyApp()
window.show()
app.exec()
```

I unsuccesfully tried with `self.progress_bar.setAttribute(Qt.WidgetAttribute.WA_DeleteOnClose, False)`...

Comment: I cannot reproduce this at all. Cancelling the dialog makes no difference. This is on arch-linux using either Qt-5.15.10 with PyQt-5.15.9 / PySide-5.15.10 or Qt-6.5.2 with PyQt-6.5.2 / PySide-6.5.2.

Comment: I run it on Python 3.10, PyQt 5 and Ubuntu 23.04

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution. The provided example works if replacing

- `self.progress_bar.setMinimumDuration(1000)`

with

- `self.worker.started.connect(self.progress_bar.show)`